# Geocoder in Rails with MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongomapper, rails-geocoder

I have used geocoder in my ruby on rails application for a while but when I moved computer I can't get it working with the include statement in my model. I use a Mongo database and keep getting this error:

uninitialized constant Geocoder::Model::MongoMapper

As per instructions (and it worked before) I am using this line at the top of my model file:

include Geocoder::Model::MongoMapper

I am using these gems:

geocoder 1.1.2
mongo 1.6.4
mongo_mapper 0.11.1

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason re-installing my activesupport gems made the application run again.../confused